# Auto scroll the swing container

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, autoscroll

i have made a custom component which is a container and contains a number of other components (JPanels, JLabels, etc).
I want to make this container autoscroll when a drag-n-drop operation occurs.
Now i have to move the the scrolls manually.

Comment: Try taking a look at [`JViewport#setViewPosition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html)

Answer (score 1):

Add your Custom component in JScrollPane

```
CustomControl cc=new customControl();
JScrollPane pane=new JScrollPane(cc);
```

First Add All Control in CustomControl